# Disable some ASP.Net validation controls when a checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using old fashioned ASP.NET validation (ugh) for a checkout process. I have a checkbox -"I'll call with my credit card details"-. If checked I need to disable the required field validator and cc validator for the credit card number both on the client and on the Postback.

How do it do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable the validators **client-side** (in javascript):

```
function disable(validatorId)
{
   var validator = document.getElementById(validatorId);
   ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
}
```

Where validatorId is the clientID of the validator to be disabled. See [this page](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/use-client-side-javascript-to-disable-aspnet-validators/000289.aspx) for a complete example.

Comment: I needed to add the following after ValidatorEnable() to hide any existing validator messages.

validator.isvalid = true;  
ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);

Comment: A better solution will be using jQuery selector of those validators where they may have a common css state, such as, hidden

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the validators **server-side**:

```
MyFieldValidator.Enabled = MyCheckBox.Checked

Page.Validate()
If Page.IsValid Then
   'stuff
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're disabling server side then you can do

```
button1.CausesValidation = False
```

in your CheckChangedEvent this is more helpful if you have a lot of validators and need to disable them all.

Comment: protected void NoValidation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitButton.CausesValidation = !NoValidation.Checked;
    }